# Intuition for the definition of an accumulation point.

Tags: real-analysis

I have been given the following definition of an accumulation point:
"A point $x\in\mathbb R$ is called an accumulation point of $E\subset\mathbb R$, if $x$ is a point of closure of $E\setminus\{x\}$."

I'm struggling to build an intuition for this definition. Specifically, what differentiates a point of closure from an accumulation point? Is there a neat graphical representation for me to better understand this?

Comment: The beginning of the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adherent_point) for "point of closure" describes the subtle difference between the definitions of "point of closure"/"adherent point" and "accumulation point"/"limit point".

Comment: In the reals (or in any metric space), $x$ is an accumulation point of $E$ means that there are points in $E$ (besides $x,$ in case $x$ is in $E$; note that in this definition, $x$ can be in $E,$ but $x$ does not have to be in $E)$ that are arbitrarily close to $x.$ An equivalent formulation is that there exists a sequence of points in $E,$ none of which is equal to $x,$ that converges to $x.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds as though in your presentation, "point of closure" i.e. "closure point" is the primary concept, and then the accumulation point concept is built upon the earlier concept.

So you'll want to have a nice intuition for what is a closure point $y$ for a given set $E$.

I like to view the requirement  in two stages. The first stage is a static visualization, while the second is dynamic.

1. If you draw the open unit disc centered at $y$, and look inside it, you will see at least one point that belongs to the set $E$.
2. Now grab that open unit disc (radius $\epsilon=1$) and begin to shrink it around its center $y$. As you do so (for any $0<\epsilon<1$) the same observation must always be true: you will see at least one point that belongs to the set $E$.

Now your requested graphical representation for "accumulation point" is just a variation of the above, but "puncturing" or "deleting" the point $x$ from $E$. (In effect disqualifying $x$ from being one of the "at least one" points, if it even belongs to $E$, which is not required.)

Next to "differentiate a point of closure from an accumulation point." The best way to see the difference is by the introduction of a third type of point, called an isolated point of a given set $E$ (for definitions see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adherent_point).

For instance if $E=\{1\}\cup[3,4),$ then $x=1\in \mathbb{R}$ is an isolated point of closure for set $E$, but is not an accumulation point for $E$.